# Spring Batch ValidatingItemProcessor with ItemListener

Tags: spring-batch, spring-validator

I am using an ItemListenerSupport to log errors to a database as part of a Spring Batch Job. I am validating the entries as they are processed using a ValidatingItemProcessor that implements `org.springframework.validation.Validator`.

The issue is that if the item does not pass validation I am not sure how to get the validation errors into the ItemListener for logging. The `afterProcess` method is called of `ItemProcessListener` and has no way of receiving an exception. Is this possible?

```
    public SimpleStepBuilder<MyItem, MyItem> simpleStepBuilder(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
            ItemProcessor validatingItemProcessor, ItemWriter itemWriter,
            MyItemErrorItemListener MyItemErrorItemListenerSupport,
            MyItemSkipListener MyItemSkipListener) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get(JOB_NAME).<MyItem, MyItem>chunk(chunkSize)
                .processor(validatingItemProcessor) // Calls afterProcess(MyItem src, MyItem result) with result being null
                .listener((ItemProcessListener) MyItemErrorItemListenerSupport)
                .writer(itemWriter)
                .listener((ItemWriteListener) MyItemErrorItemListenerSupport);
    }
```

and an example Validator:

```
public class MyItemValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(@NotNull Object target, Errors errors) {
        MyItem myItem = (MyItem) target;
        validate(target, errors);
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(errors.getAllErrors())) {
            log.error("Validation Errors: [{}]", errors.getAllErrors());
        }
    }

}
```

I could throw an exception in the Validator if errors appear, but this kills the job

Answer (score 1):

You should throw a `ValidationException` and declare it as a skippable exception in your step. With that, you should be able to intercept invalid items with a `SkipListener#skipInProcess`.

If you use `SpringValidator` as delegate in `ValidatingItemProcessor`, it will throw a `ValidationException` that wrap a `BindException` which gives you access to all validation errors for the invalid item.